# What environment variables control dyld?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, dyld

There are a bunch of environment variables that control dyld launch, several of them very useful for debugging performance problems. Not all of them are documented.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

These ones are explained in the dyld man page (at least on macOS 10.13)

```
DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH
DYLD_FALLBACK_FRAMEWORK_PATH
DYLD_VERSIONED_FRAMEWORK_PATH
DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
DYLD_FALLBACK_LIBRARY_PATH
DYLD_VERSIONED_LIBRARY_PATH
DYLD_PRINT_TO_FILE
DYLD_SHARED_REGION
DYLD_INSERT_LIBRARIES
DYLD_FORCE_FLAT_NAMESPACE
DYLD_IMAGE_SUFFIX
DYLD_PRINT_OPTS
DYLD_PRINT_ENV
DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES
DYLD_BIND_AT_LAUNCH
DYLD_DISABLE_DOFS
DYLD_PRINT_APIS
DYLD_PRINT_BINDINGS
DYLD_PRINT_INITIALIZERS
DYLD_PRINT_REBASINGS
DYLD_PRINT_SEGMENTS
DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS
DYLD_PRINT_DOFS
DYLD_PRINT_RPATHS
DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DIR
DYLD_SHARED_CACHE_DONT_VALIDATE
```

This one is documented in `man dyld`, but isn't listed in the list at the top:

```
DYLD_PRINT_STATISTICS_DETAILS
```

These are undocumented:

```
DYLD_ROOT_PATH
DYLD_PATHS_ROOT
DYLD_DISABLE_PREFETCH
DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES_POST_LAUNCH
DYLD_NEW_LOCAL_SHARED_REGIONS
DYLD_NO_FIX_PREBINDING
DYLD_PREBIND_DEBUG
DYLD_PRINT_TO_STDERR
DYLD_PRINT_WEAK_BINDINGS
DYLD_PRINT_WARNINGS
DYLD_PRINT_CS_NOTIFICATIONS
DYLD_PRINT_INTERPOSING
DYLD_PRINT_CODE_SIGNATURES
DYLD_USE_CLOSURES
DYLD_IGNORE_PREBINDING
DYLD_SKIP_MAIN
```

`DYLD_ROOT_PATH` and `DYLD_PATHS_ROOT` appear to be synonyms and allow you to reset the "root" for searching for libraries/frameworks/etc. This is available on macOS/iPhoneSimulator but not iOS.

`DYLD_DISABLE_PREFETCH` disables the pre-fetching of the content of __DATA and __LINKEDIT segments.

`DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES_POST_LAUNCH` is the same as DYLD_PRINT_LIBRARIES but prints them right after launch has finished.

`DYLD_NEW_LOCAL_SHARED_REGIONS` and `DYLD_NO_FIX_PREBINDING` are ignored and don't do anything anymore.

`DYLD_PREBIND_DEBUG` prints out debug information on why prebinding was not used.

`DYLD_PRINT_TO_STDERR` only applies to iOS and forces output to stderr (instead of stdout) to help it show up on console logs.

`DYLD_PRINT_WEAK_BINDINGS` prints debug information on weak bindings.

`DYLD_PRINT_WARNINGS` prints a bunch of warnings (mostly regards to closures and how they are being used).

`DYLD_PRINT_CS_NOTIFICATIONS` prints information about the core symbolicator.

`DYLD_PRINT_INTERPOSING` prints details about interposes that occur.

`DYLD_PRINT_CODE_SIGNATURES` prints details about code signatures (specifically successes and failures).

`DYLD_USE_CLOSURES` is a dyld3 feature, but doesn't appear to work for anybody non-internal (need CSR_ALLOW_APPLE_INTERNAL set).

`DYLD_IGNORE_PREBINDING` has three values ("all", "app", "nonsplit") with nonsplit being the default if a value is not supplied.

`DYLD_SKIP_MAIN` is an apple only feature used for testing dyld (need CSR_ALLOW_APPLE_INTERNAL set).